# looping over python list and string formating

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

loop a list in string formatted list

I have the following variables

```
BUILDING = "123"
SIDE = "ProductionA"
TODO = "traveling without moving"
```

I have the following list

```
OS = ["Linux", "Unix", "Windows"]
```

I create a formatted string list

```
FLIST = [
"I am installing in {}, side {} using the {} cd".format (BUILDING,SIDE,o),
"Other random stuff",
"Even more random stuff: ".format(TODO)]
```

I want to loop the loop the list:

```
for o in OS:
    print(o)
    for f in FLIST:
        print(f)
```

I am hoping to get:

```
"I am installing in 123, side ProductionA using the Linux cd"
"Other random stuff",
"Even more random stuff: traveling without moving"

"I am installing in 123, side ProductionA using the Unix cd"
"Other random stuff",
"Even more random stuff: traveling without moving"

"I am installing in 123, side ProductionA using the Windows cd"
"Other random stuff",
"Even more random stuff: traveling without moving"
```

The `print(o)` works, i am getting the values(`Linux`,`Unix`,`Window`) if i omit the OS in the format string.

```
I am installing in {}, side {} using the {} cd".format (BUILDING,SIDE)
```

But the o variable is not accepted by the formatted list, the error i am getting is:

> NameError: name 'o' is not defined.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: `FLIST` should be function taking `o` as an input.

Comment: This sounds like an issue of scoping. The items in `FLIST` don't know about `o` because it's in a different scope

Comment: 1- FLIST declaration should go within for loop, 2- the " after your first format() within FLIST should be removed

Comment: in `FLIST` just replace `o` with `"{}"`

Comment: Thank you all for quick respondig, the answer of @mAhMoUdDaFeR was best in my case, since his answer kept the most of my list in tact. Although the other ones from Dan and Codelt were informative too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try making a function `FLIST` that takes o as a parameter:

```
def FLIST(o):
    return [
        "I am installing in {}, side {} using the {} cd".format (BUILDING,SIDE,o), 
        "Other random stuff",
        "Even more random stuff: ".format(TODO)
    ]
```

then use this function:

```
for o in OS:
    print(o)
    for f in FLIST(o):
        print(f)
```

Answer (score 4):

I have placed the `FLIST` inside the loop. Try,

```
BUILDING = "123"
SIDE = "ProductionA"
TODO = "traveling without moving"

OS = ["Linux", "Unix", "Windows"]

for o in OS:
    print(o)
    FLIST = ["I am installing in {}, side {} using the {} cd".format (BUILDING,SIDE,o),"Other random stuff","Even more random stuff: {}".format(TODO)]
    for f in FLIST:
        print(f)
```

Output:

```
Linux
I am installing in 123, side ProductionA using the Linux cd
Other random stuff
Even more random stuff: traveling without moving
Unix
I am installing in 123, side ProductionA using the Unix cd
Other random stuff
Even more random stuff: traveling without moving
Windows
I am installing in 123, side ProductionA using the Windows cd
Other random stuff
Even more random stuff: traveling without moving
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/FunnyQuintessentialEmulator)

Answer (score 3):

`FLIST` should rather be function taking `o` as an input:

```
BUILDING = "123"
SIDE = "ProductionA"
TODO = "traveling without moving"

# Note f-strings only work in python 3.6+, revert to .format() if you need to use an older version
def make_flist(operating_system):
    return [
        f"I am installing in {BUILDING}, side {SIDE} using the {operating_system} cd",
        "Other random stuff",
        f"Even more random stuff: {TODO}"
    ]

operating_systems = ["Linux", "Unix", "Windows"]

for operating_system in operating_systems:
    print(operating_system)
    for statement in make_flist(operating_system):
        print(statement)
```

Comment: `o` isn't defined in the for loop.